# r studio cmd+s sourcing rather than saving

Tags: save, rstudio

Run into a bizarre problem where R studio (latest version - Version 1.0.136 on mac) has suddenly started sourcing the current file rather than saving it when cmd+s is pressed.

I have gone through the keyboard shortcuts and removed all those pertaining to the source() function, but it is still doing it, and also uninstalled/reinstalled rstudio, neither of which helped.

Any suggestions on how to fix!?

Many thanks

Answer (score 5):

Ok sorted! There is a small button at the top left of the code window called "source on save" which I had somehow checked.